# Chrome Extension - Javascript - Control Youtube Video with Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I am trying to write (learn) a very simple chrome extension using JS to control video playing on Youtube.  When I click stop, the video should stop, but it is not stopping.  Please guide me where I should look for solution.  Below is the popup.html

```
<a href="#" onclick="stop()">Stop</a>
```

Below is JS.

```
window.onload = function()
{
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function()
{
player.stopVideo();
}
}
```

Comment: hi player variable u have decalred  is the instance of  YT.Player i believe..

Comment: i am trying to control YT player on youtube.com.  Is it not possible?

Comment: S its possible but before helping need to know wat have tried and ur task ahead..\

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!  I want to first learn to control youtube video on youtube.  So, when we click on the omnibox of the toolbar, we can see stop hyperlink.  If we click on it, it should stop the video.  First i want to achieve this.  Later I would add playing, increasing speed, decreasing speed, repeat, etc.  But, now I am unable to achieve the basic function.

Comment: i hope with ur coding ur video is loaded and playing if its then follow below link will do help ur task ahead..https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player

Answer (score 0):

In current HTML5 player of youtube you can do this easily using:

`document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play()`

I created a chrome extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-playback-control/okbcoijdeebocmahlanbfemnckjonfnh). Also you can check the code [here](https://github.com/shahankit/youtube-playback-control).